# Is there a gccemacs (native-comp) build for MS-Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, gccemacs

I use the official binaries (28.0.50 prerelease) for MS Windows. I am using gccemacs on my home Linux machines, and feel like native-comp on Windows would be really useful for me at work. However, I don't have a MingW toolchain installed. Is anyone providing gccemacs binaries for MS-Windows?

Comment: I would also appreciate gccemacs on windows. I think about installing it using [msys2/mingw64](https://www.msys2.org/) platform for windows. I once successfully compiled emacs on windows with this platform. By the way, this is the recommended procedure to build emacs on windows (see [INSTALL.W64](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/nt/INSTALL.W64)). I have not yet tried to compile gccemacs the same way. Trouble is that the library `libgccjit` is required, as far as I understand, which I did not find in msys2/mingw64 packages. This library is part of the gcc distribution but, is u

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on the main answer, but I think that `--with-nativecomp` should be `--with-native-compilation`, based on https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2021-02/msg02011.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are unofficial builds https://github.com/kiennq/emacs-build/releases via https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GccEmacs

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to many people and their work [here](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=45303), the emacs native-compilation feature is now available on windows 10. Still yet you have to compile it yourself (from the Emacs master branch).

First install msys2/mingw64 and all the required development packages for emacs (see nt/INSTALL.W64 in emacs source). Then install gcc and, of course, libgccjit. This later is now available as a regular mingw64 package.

Then, still following nt/INSTALL.W64 :

```sh
./autogen.sh
./configure --without-dbus --without-pop --with-native-compilation --prefix=/your/install/path
make -j$(nproc) # or make NATIVE_FULL_AOT=1 -j$(nproc) // longer
make install
```

Then create a batch script with :

```
@ECHO OFF

TITLE Emacs - native-compilation

SET HOME=C:\Users\yourname

C:
CD %HOME%

IF EXIST .emacs.d\server\server DEL .emacs.d\server\server

SET PATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\local\bin;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;%PATH%

C:\msys64\mingw64\local\bin\emacsclientw.exe -n -a C:\msys64\mingw64\local\bin\runemacs.exe -e "(make-frame-visible)"
```

And then, you can run it by clicking on the batch script as any other windows 10 program.

I assume your msys64 installation is at C:\msys64 and that emacs - nativecomp is installed at C:\msys64\mingw64\local so as to not interfere with the default emacs 27.1 mingw64 package.

It is mandatory to add "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin" to the windows path because emacs needs some libraries at startup which are in there.

Comment: While of interest and generally helpful to Emacs users, this doesn't seem to answer the question "Is anyone providing gccemacs binaries for MS-Windows?" at all. It's essentially supplementary commentary (much appreciated, but not an answer).

Comment: You are right but as said, no package at the moment to my knowledge and in the initial message, it is more precisely asked for gccemacs binaries. My answer aimed at showing the author's question how to get some himself. That said, in following days I will try to build a mingw64 package. Regards

Comment: Would you have a look into your *.bat lines, please? The last line seems very strange.

Comment: Is there something like AUR / yay for MSYS, similar to Arch ? I guess I'm asking for a PKGBUILD :D

Comment: @KeksDose : I have updated my answer, the last line is a way to start emacs with windows 10 I borrowed somewhere else, but they are other (simpler) ways

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an "official" one at the moment. The windows port is a little flaky right now. Once it has had a bit more time to mature, or once it merges to master there will be an "official" snapshot (if that is not a contradiction in terms) of it.

Answer (score 2):

I created a MINGW `PKGBUILD` file for native compilation Emacs. You can find it [here](https://github.com/WolfgangRamos/MINGW-packages/tree/emacs-native-compilation/mingw-w64-emacs-native-compilation). A MINGW package is also available as a pre-release version [here](https://github.com/WolfgangRamos/MINGW-packages/releases/tag/emacs-native-compilation-v1).

You can install the pre-release version by using:

```
# Open mingw shell (e.g. msys2)
pacman -U mingw-w64-x86_64-emacs-native-compilation-*-any.pkg.tar.zst
```

The request for merging this into `MINGW-packages` main fork (thus making Emacs native comp available via MINGW's `pacman`) was not approved, because native compilation is still an experimental feature. So for now, I can only provide it on my fork of the `MINGW-packages` repository.

Comment: `source=("emacs-git::git://git.savannah.gnu.org/emacs.git#branch=feature/native-comp")` is no longer needed (and will become stale) as `feature/native-comp` was merged to `master` the other day.  See [Emacs commit 289000e](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=emacs.git;a=commit;h=289000eee729689b0cf362a21baa40ac7f9506f6) and also https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2021-04/msg01175.html